# How to make the TS compiler know an unknown variable has some properties (without the usage of `any` type)

Tags: typescript, types, compiler-errors

```js
function f(): unknown {
    return {abc: "ABC"};
}

const a = f();

if (a && a instanceof Object && a.hasOwnProperty("abc")) {
    console.log(a.abc);
}
```

I have a variable `a` which is the `unknown` type at first (>= TypeScript 3.0).
I want to use the `abc` property of `a` inside an *if statement* when `a` has the property.

[image: VS code ts error screenshot]

However, as the above VS code screenshot shows, the TypeScript compiler gives the `TS2339` error even though I checked `a.hasOwnProperty("abc")` in the if condition.

> Property 'abc' does not exist on type 'object'. ts(2339)

I know that I can bypass this error by casting `a` to `any` type, but it will make the compiler ignore the typos of members' names, and it will be bad if there are many properties in `a` and many things to do with the variable `a`.

Is there a way for the TypeScript compiler to know that `a` has certain properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{ [index: string]: unknown }` instead of `unknown` to tell TypeScript your object is a dictionary of unknown properties.

```
declare const unfamiliar: { [index: string]: unknown };

if ('foo' in unfamiliar) {
  unfamiliar.foo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the assertion that `a` is an `Object`. The `Object` type does not contain `abc` so the following assertion does not make a difference.
If you only keep the `a.hasOwnProperty()` assertion it should work.

Comment: It will work if `a` were `any` type. However, `a` is `unknown` type, so it will not remove the compile error in this case.